# React twilio.Js Library Accept Incoming Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I am trying to accept incoming calls with the twilio.Js Library. (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client)

I am listening for the incoming calls like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    Twilio.Device.incoming((conn) => {
        console.log('Incoming connection from ' + conn.parameters.From);
    });
}
```

I know that I can just call conn.accept(); in the Twilio.Device.incoming function, however for my component to work, I would need to be able to accept the call outside of the componentDidMount() function.

So preferably I would have a function like this:

```js
acceptCall() {
 // Do something to accept call
}
```

Is there any expert here, that could quickly help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself.

What I need to do is the following:

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props);
        
    this.state = {
        inboundConn: null
    };
}
    
// Initialize after component creation
componentDidMount() {
   Twilio.Device.incoming((conn) => {
      this.setState({
         inboundConn: conn
      });
   });
}
    
acceptCall() {
   this.state.inboundConn.accept();
}
```